# How to mark a NonNullable reference property as safe?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have an entity which I use in my EntityFramework model.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

After enabling nullable reference types compiler gives me a warning:

```
Warning CS8618  Non-nullable property 'Value' is uninitialized.
```

I know that this property is not nullable in the database and its safe.

Is there any way to mark this property as safe other than disabling the warnings in the class with `#pragma warning disable`?

My first instinct was trying to mark the type as safe with `!` like this

```
public string! Value { get; set; }
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Heed the warning. Nothing says this property is safe. The warning tells you that variable is *not* initialized and hence, null. Even if the *field* in the database is non-nullable, a query may return `NULL`. The results of a LEFT JOIN with no matching records in the right-hand table will contain NULL for all missing values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, this is more complicated than I thought

Comment: Could you perhaps mitigate this my providing a default value (I guess this would depend on whether an empty string was a legal value or not in your case)? `public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 9):

See an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973095/245460) to my similar question. If you ensure by some business rules the non-nullability (validation in my case), it is better to tell to consumers of your class that some property will be never null by using the non-nullable property and handle compiler warning by using this construct.

```
public class Entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; } = null!;
   public string Value { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate answers, that is what *closing* questions is for.

Answer (score 0):

You on the right way.

public string? Value { get; set; }

Comment: But the type is not nullable and will always have value

Comment: That's *not* safe