# Non-nullable string type, how to use with Asp.Net Core options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

MS states [Express your design intent more clearly with nullable and non-nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types).

My intent is to express, that properties `Issuer` and `Audience` in my `JwtOptions` are never null. Which is very reasonable intent for consumers of these options, is not? These not null values are ensured by Asp.Net Core validation described below.

But if `JwtOptions` has not all properties initialized by the constructor, so C# 8 compiler reports

> Warning   CS8618  Non-nullable property 'Issuer' is uninitialized.

And for some technical reasons, Asp.Net Core options cannot have a constructor with parameters. So I am stuck with my intent. I can switch nullable checking off or declare `Issuer` and other properties nullable, but I think this is not the best solution.

Is there any elegant solution in this case?

Snippet from csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have these strongly typed options in Asp.Net Core application:

```
public class JwtOptions
{
    [Required]
    public string Issuer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Audience { get; set; }

}
```

Options are configured by a next code in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddOptions<JwtOptions>()
            .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("JwtOption"))
            .ValidateDataAnnotations();
    }
```

and consumed by `HomeController`:

```
    public HomeController(IOptions<JwtOptions> options)
    {
        string audience = options.Value.Audience;
        string issuer = options.Value.Issuer;
    }
```

As you can see, nor `Audience` nor `Issuer` cannot be null for the consumer. Make these properties nullable makes no sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as the compiler knows, it has not been initialized and can be `null`. Use the `!(null-forgiving operator)` as a last resort (and leave a comment explaining why you used `!`.

```
// This should be set by the options binding
public string Issuer { get; set; } = null!;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is some kind of quick and dirty solution, as you can see, the comment is required for clarity... Not very elegant. I don't know if it can be done better?

Comment: @KarelKral i dont think so. this is the suggested pattern from mads and bill with their NDC talks.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know. Clearly, non-nullable reference types bring many challenges.

Comment: @KarelKral it’s a whole new world but the benefits outweigh the negatives