# Positional record attributes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, record, nullable-reference-types

Thank you to the reviewers for finding the duplicate: [How do I target attributes for a record class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778276/how-do-i-target-attributes-for-a-record-class)

and [.NET 5.0 Web API won't work with record featuring required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934513/net-5-0-web-api-wont-work-with-record-featuring-required-properties) is related too.

I'm trying to understand why 3. Positional record attributes don't work below.

It is a new ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Web App with source here https://github.com/djhmateer/record-test

https://daveabrock.com/2020/11/18/simplify-api-models-with-records seems to have got it working with an API.

```cs
public class LoginModelNRTB : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    // there will never be an InputModel on get
    // but if we set to nullable InputModel then the cshtml will produce dereference warnings
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973095/26086
    // so this will get rid of the warnings as we are happy we will never get dereferences on the front
    // ie we are happy the underlying framework will not produce null reference exceptions
    public InputModel Input { get; set; } = null!;


    // 1. Original Class which works
    //public class InputModel
    //{
    //    // don't need required as Email property is non nullable
    //    //[Required]
    //    // makes sure a regex fires to be in the correct email address form
    //    [EmailAddress]
    //    // there should always be an email posted, but maybe null if js validator doesn't fire
    //    // we are happy the underlying framework handles it, 
    //    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;

    //    // When the property is called Password we don't need a [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    //    //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
    //    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

    //    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    //    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    //}

    // 2. Record which works
    //public record InputModel
    //{
    //    [EmailAddress]
    //    public string Email { get; init; } = null!;

    //    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    //    public string PasswordB { get; init; } = null!;

    //    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    //    public bool RememberMe { get; init; }
    //}

    // 3. Positional record attributes not being picked up
    public record InputModel(
        string Email,
        [DataType(DataType.Password)] string PasswordB,
        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")] bool RememberMe);


    public void OnGet() { }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Input property of type InputModel is bound because of the [BindProperty] attribute
            Log.Information($"Success! {Input}");
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }

        Log.Information($"Failure on ModelState validation {Input}");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [proposal specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#properties):

> Attributes can be applied to the synthesized auto-property and its backing field by using `property:` or `field:` targets for attributes syntactically applied to the corresponding record parameter.

Try next:

```
public record InputModel(
    string Email,
    [property:DataType(DataType.Password)] string PasswordB,
    [property:Display(Name = "Remember me?")] bool RememberMe);
```

Based on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciAiBLAzgBwDYEMBPAQQBdSAndAIwFdSBTALjMpvoYG8BfWWBRBQYBjAPYUAJogCSAO2z0AsqIkNcACliJtO7SAgAGRAFEAtvnS4ANFt07bdxAG1sFUdgYVShJhhwFCAF1EalFRXEQAJQZTGOpPRQYASgBuIA===) decompilation, the attributes should be emitted for generated properties.

Without this target the attribute gets emitted as attribute on corresponding record [constructor parameter](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciAiBLAzgBwDYEMBPAQQBdSAndAIwFdSBTALjMpvoYG8BfWWBRBQYBjAPYUAJogCSAO2z0AsqIkNcAChAQADIgCiAW3zpcAGkQBtDDgKEAuomqjRuRACUGBz9QYVFDAEoAbiA===).

Comment: Thank you @Guru - good to understand what is happening. Ultimately this strategy didn't work with ASP.NET Core Razor pages because of a similar reason to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934513/net-5-0-web-api-wont-work-with-record-featuring-required-properties